# linear regression degrees of freedom

Tags: regression, excel

Via trial and error where I guess the number of statistical degrees of freedom, I have determined that the single variable linear regression "automatically" performed by Excel provides a p-value for the Y-axis-intercept  that is identical to the one that can be calculated by "explicit" Excel functions as follows:

`2*T.DIST(0-t,n-2,TRUE)`

(*The p-value is for the null hypothesis that the Y-axis-intercept is zero.*)

Here `T.DIST` is the function name and it is left tailed, hence the need to flip the sign on the t-statistic. This flip operation is visible as the `0-`, or "zero minus".

Here `t` is the t-statistic.

Here `n` is the number of observations.

Here `TRUE` means the function operates in cumulative mode.

The second argument to the function is the statistical degrees of freedom. I guessed that the value would be `n-1` which was wrong and then I guessed it would be `n-2`. Why should the statistical degrees of freedom be 2 less than the number of observations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this should be $n-p$ degrees of freedom, where $p$ is number of parameters in linear regression equation.

In single variable linear regression, you have 2 parameters: intercept and slope.